# How do I compare System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut to System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How do I tell that a `System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut` is the same as a `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` object?

For example, I am using a shortcut like: `Shortcut.CtrlShiftA`. The KeyDown event handler has an argument of type `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs'. I am hoping I don't have to do a big switch statement.

Comment: "The KeyPress event handler has an argument of type \`System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs'." -- No, it doesn't. The [`KeyPress` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) handler has an argument of type [`KeyPressEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). I suspect you're subscribing to the [`KeyDown` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, is that right?

Comment: You are correct. Fixed the question. It wasn't a material part of the question, just background information on why I am trying to figure this out.

Comment: An important bit to know what you're looking for though :) If you did try the `KeyPress` event, things would be a lot more complicated, but `KeyDown` gives you the `Keys`, which as answered by Hans Passant on that other question has values that are by design 100% identical to those of `Shortcut`.